# php-how to move files to the folder created using userid (upload files)

Tags: php, upload

Once the is uploaded i am creating folder based on Application id which is unique.

The problem i am facing here is, once i upload ,files are uploade out side respected  folders.

even folder is getting created.

Can any any one help on this!!!

```
$path = $file['name'];
$path_user = '/home/devestctrl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/'.'/'.$send_id;
if (!file_exists($path_user)) {
    if (mkdir( $path_user,0766,false )) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$path_user.$path)) {
            echo"inside 2"."<br>";
            echo"Your File Successfully Uploaded";
        }                 
    }
}
```

Comment: `out side respected folders.` means ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar oustside application id

Comment: $path_user = '/home/devestctrl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/'.'/'.$send_id.'/';    add the slash at last

Comment: `Files/'.'/'.$send_id`, this should be `Files'/'.$send_id`

Comment: use `$path_user = '/home/devestctrl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/'.$send_id.'/';`

Comment: folder (files)-------inside that i am inserting another folder (application id) inside that i am inserting files

Comment: @jothi  Thanks ,that didn't work for me.

Comment: @NanaPartykar ,Thanks a lot....It works fyn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove extra `/` between `est_collaboration/Files/'` And `.$send_id`.

Append `/` in last. Like

`$path_user = '/home/devestctrl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/'.$send_id.'/';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a slash between `$path_user` and `$path`:

```
$path_user = '/home/devestctrl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/est_collaboration/Files/'.'/'.$send_id;
if (!is_dir($path_user)) {
    if (!mkdir($path_user, 0766, false)) {
        die('Directory cannot be created'); // handle this exception
    }
}

if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path_user . '/' . $path)) {
// ----- You are missing this slash -------------------^^^------------
    echo "inside 2"."<br>";
    echo "Your File Successfully Uploaded";
}
```